# concatenate 2D array with 3rd dimension

Tags: python, numpy

I have this:

```
fs = fs + np.concatenate((r,g,b), axis=0)
```

fs.shape returns (379, 754, 3) while r, g and b returns (379, 754)

How can I introduce the third dimensions into r, g and b?

Comment: Can you show a minimal example for `fs` and `r`, `g`, and `b` along with the desired result?

Comment: I want to add a third dimension to the matrix created with np.concatenate((r,g,b), axis=0), so if the matrix is A = np.concatenate((r,g,b), axis = 0), I want A.shape to be (379, 754, 3), instead of (379, 754)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you will try `fs = fs + np.concatenate((r,g,b), axis=0)` with another axis
it will get another 2 arguments and youu can get your b

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`np.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) on the last dimension instead of using `np.concatenation`:

```
>>> r, g, b = np.random.rand(3, 379, 754)


>>> np.stack((r, g, b), axis=-1).shape
(379, 754, 3)
```

Comment: The thing is r,g,b are given an they have 2 dimensions, not three

Comment: @Zyder I unpacked the `np.random.rand(3, 379, 754)` for conciseness but they do end up as 2-dimensional tensors shaped `(379, 754)`. You can try it out and look at the shapes of `r`, `g` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this:

```
fs = fs + np.stack((r,g,b), axis=2)
```

Also thanks @Ivan for your help!

Comment: Yes that's what I wrote: here `axis=2` corresponds to `axis=-1`. Please either accept your answer or mine (by clicking on the green checkmark on the left).